# Login failure: unknown user name or bad password

Tags: authentication, tfs, error-handling, visual-studio-2012

We are running Visual Studio 2012 and Team Foundation Server 2012.  In the Team Explorer window, I am able to successfully connect to our TFS environment.  However, when I select the Security link under Team Project or Team Project Collection, I receive a message "Team Foundation Server: Login Failure: unknown user name or bad password".

I have not found a log file or anything in any event viewer file that helps debug this problem.

- Is there a log file I can search for that contains some 'hints' as to want the connection problem is?
- where are your credentials stored on your locale machine that are used to connection team foundation?

Answer (score 5):

We realized that the root cause for this issue is that Visual Studio is trying to open a browser using the same credentials used to connect to TFS. If those credentials are not allowed to run processes on your machine (I suspect in your case it’s domain users on a different domain which is not trusted by the client domain) then opening the browser will fail. That explains why you can hit those URLs using a browser instance that is opened using your own credentials.This will be fixed in a future release of visual studio.

Answer (score 3):

In TFS 2012, the management interface for permissions and project settings has largely shifted to **Team Web Access**.

Clicking any of the following settings from Team Explorer 2012 will produce the "Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password" error:

•Team Project Collection > Security

•Team Project Collection > Group Membership

•Team Project > Security

•Team Project > Group Membership

•Team Project > Work Item Areas

•Team Project > Work Item Iterations

•Team Project > Project Alerts

Comment: This is all true, but isn't an answer. Did you find a work around?

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem. To correct it (temporaly), you must run VS 2012 with this command:

```
C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /netonly /user:{domain\loginname} "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
```

Change {domain\loginname} by the domain and login name of your tfs domain account. A console will ask for your password and all works!

Comment: I'm +1 this because while it's a known issue, this truly does allow one to work remotely from another computer outside of your domain and works beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced the same issue with TFS. I found a solution for that. You have to remap your workspaces in your PC or Remote server. If you have any uncommitted changes in your projects, you have to keep backup, otherwise you will lost your changes.

Steps -

- Go to Workspaces in Visual Studio

  File-> Source Control -> Advanced -> Workspaces
- Remove the current workspaces.
- Remap the projects again.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue with TFS Express 2012. I don't know if my situation applies to you but here are the facts:

- My TFS instance was running on a remote server.
- Neither that server or my local machine were on a domain.
- I was using the same user account name on both machines but with
  different passwords.
- Setting the passwords to be same fixed the problem.

The functions that weren't working were the ones that launch the project website, which I could navigate to directly anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix the issue myself by mapping a drive to the area where TFS appears to have A cache located - but then I have 2 separate workspaces going across 2 separate domains